# Opayo API - Unable to validate signature

Tags: c#, asp.net, md5, opayo

I have been trying to connect to the Opayo 'Reporting & Admin API' and use the command 'getTransactionDetail' (https://developer-eu.elavon.com/docs/opayo-reporting-api/reporting-commands/gettransactiondetail), but keep getting back error 0010, which indicates that the API Cannot validate the signature value. We have been able to login with our Vendor/Username/Password combination, validating that they are all correct.

The code we are using when sending a POST to the API is below - with certain elements blocked out for security purposes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;

public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string signature = "<command>getTransactionDetail</command><vendor>[Vendor]</vendor><user>[User]</user><vendortxcode>[VendorTXCode]</vendortxcode><password>[Password]</password>";

        using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
        {
            byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(signature);
            byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(hashBytes[i].ToString("X2"));
            }
            signature = sb.ToString();
        }

        string xmlToPost = "<vspaccess><command>getTransactionDetail</command><vendor>[Vendor]</vendor><user>[User]</user><vendortxcode>[VendorTXCode]</vendortxcode><signature>" + signature + "</signature></vspaccess>";

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = "https://test.sagepay.com";
            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

            var content = new NameValueCollection()
            {
                { "XML", xmlToPost }
            };

            string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.UploadValues("/access/access.htm", content));
        }
    }
}
```

Any help in resolving this issue would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out due to the fact we were using Forms integration for our initial payment, we had to instead use the following API documentation: https://developer-eu.elavon.com/docs/opayo/spec/api-reference

More specifically this part related to repeats: https://developer-eu.elavon.com/docs/opayo/spec/api-reference#operation/createTransaction

Note the code examples on the right hand side!

Comment: Do you have an updated links by any chance? These both now return 404, I am having the same issue and the docs are somewhat lacking..

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps others looking for Opayo Admin and Reporting API help:

I had the same issue, so I created a NuGet package for the API-client code here: https://github.com/joeratzer/opayo-admin-and-reporting-api-client.

You can find the NuGet package here:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Joe.Opayo.Admin.Api.Client/1.1.0

The client app allows code like this:

```
var client = new OpayoAdminApiClient();
var isTest = true;
var request = new OpayoApiRequest(ApiCommandType.GetTransactionDetail, "password", isTest, "user-name", "vendor-name");
var commandSpecificXml = "<vendortxcode>01Jan2010Transaction12345</vendortxcode>"; 
return await client.ProcessApiCommandAsync<TransactionDetail>(request, commandSpecificXml);
```